# Spring Boot Google Cloud Secret Manager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I followed the instruction on [setting secret manager with GCP on Spring Boot](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/#secret-manager), I created a secret in Google Cloud, and added the following in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.password=${sm://DB_PASSWORD}
```

It didn't work, however, if I used `SecretManagerTemplate`, I can get the secret by `secretManagerTemplate.getSecretString("DB_PASSWORD");`

However, I need the datasource password to be initialized at the beginning of the application, has anyone used secret manager in spring boot?

Comment: link you have provided does not work (404)

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved magically by changing pom.xml from

```
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

to

```
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```